# Could not Invoke RNFirebaseFirestore.documentSet null

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Please find the attached screenshot for getting an error when used Firestore to set data on server. Following is the code

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

constructor() {
    super();
    this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('Product');
  }


render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={this._navigateClick} />
      </View>
    );
  }

_navigateClick = () => {
  this.ref.add({
    Desc: "Hi Hello How Are you ?",
    Img: "",
    Name:"Chair 123"
  }); 
};
```

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of your issue at https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1910 - please update your issue there with all the required information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have got same error. Please create the collection with the name 'Product' and add an dummy document. Then try.